# How to treat certain field values as null in `Elasticsearch`

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm parsing log files which for simplicity's sake let's say will have the following format :

```
{"message": "hello world", "size": 100, "forward-to": 127.0.0.1}
```

I'm indexing these lines into an **Elasticsearch** index, where I've defined a custom mapping such that `message`, `size`, and `forward-to` are of type `text`, `integer`, and `ip` respectively. However, some log lines will look like this :

```
{"message": "hello world", "size": "-", "forward-to": ""}
```

This leads to parsing errors when **Elasticsearch** tries to index these documents. For technical reasons, it's very much untrivial for me to pre-process these documents and change `"-"` and `""` to `null`. Is there anyway to define which values my mapping should treat as `null` ? Is there perhaps an analyzer I can write which works on any field type whatsoever that I can add to all entries in my mapping ?

Basically I'm looking for somewhat of the opposite of the `null_value` option. Instead of telling **Elasticsearch** what to turn a `null_value` into, I'd like to tell it what it should turn into a `null_value`. Also acceptable would be a way to tell **Elasticsearch** to simply ignore fields that look a certain way but still parse the other fields in the document.

Comment: I just realized there's an `ignore_malformed` option...

Comment: or you can create a custom analyzer that removes 'null' tokens

Answer (score 1):

So this one's easy apparently. Add the following to your mapping settings :

```
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "mapping": {
        "ignore_malformed": "true"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will still index the field (contrary to what I've understood from the documentation...) but it will be ignored during aggregations (so if you have 3 entries in an `integer` field that are `"1"`, `3`, and `"hello world"`, an averaging aggregation will yield `2`).

Keep in mind that because of the way the option was implemented (and I would say this is a bug) this still fails for and `object` that is entered as a concrete value and vice versa. If you'd like to get around that you can set the field's `enabled` value to `false` like this :

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "my_mapping_name": {
      "properties": {
        "my_unpredictable_field": {
          "enabled": false
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This comes at a price though, since this means the field won't be indexed, but the values entered will be still be stored so you can still accessing them by searching for that document through another field. This usually shouldn't be an issue as you likely won't be filtering documents based on the value of such an unpredictable field, but that depends on your specific case use. See [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/12366) for the official discussion of this issue.